# Function in R that replaces all values > with NA

Tags: r, function, vector

The function, with the arguments x and y, should take a vector x and set all values greater than or equal to y to missing value (NA). Example: `my_function(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y = y)` should return the vector: `[1] 1 2 3 NA NA NA`.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is.na<-` to *replace values with NA*.

```
my_function <- \(x, y) `is.na<-`(x, x >= y)
my_function(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 4)
#[1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also do

```
f1 <- function(x, y) replace(x, x >= y, NA)
f1(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 4)
[1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA
```